# Get sql count and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get total rows and also get rows. I have something like this

```
SELECT count(id), id 
FROM post 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what you're asking.  Please provide sample data and a desired result.  Also, please include the DBMS you're using (e.g.: `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`, etc.)

Comment: I want to get all rows and also get total count of rows even when query have limit. It's `MySql`

Comment: You probably want two queries, one for the total count and one for the first N.

Answer (score 0):

The inner query gets the count and on using [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) you can get the desired data!

```
select a.*,b.count 
from post a 
join (SELECT count(id) as count, id
      FROM post group by id) b 
  on a.id=b.id;
```